# In factory definition, assign attribute using attribute of other factory

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I have two factory_girl factories, `contact` and `user`. Contact has an attribute, `dest_user_id`, which is a foreign key to `user`, but can be NULL. For that attribute, I want to create a new user using the `user` factory, and then assign its id to `dest_user_id`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the name of the association between the two Models which describes dest_user_id? Please post the model detail for clarity.

Comment: I added the fact that dest_user_id is a foreign key. What does it matter though? The question is the same for any attribute of `user`.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you hadn't changed the relationship name along with the foreign key name as it would slightly alter the potential solution. Possible approach below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a foreign key of `dest_user_id` shouldn't change the approach, provided the relationship remains the same as the model name. Assuming that `contact` `belongs_to` `user` and a `user` either `has_one` or `has_many` `contacts`, you can achieve what you want as follows:

First create the factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    Field 1
    Field 2 
    # etc
  end

  factory :contact do
    # Add only the minimum fields required to create a contact, but not the association
    Field 1
    Field 2

    factory :contact_with_user do
      # then you add the association for this inherited factory
      # we can use 'user' here as the factory is the same as the association name
      user
    end
  end
end
```

With this setup you create a `contact` without a `user`, and therefore `dest_user_id` is `NULL` when you user `FactoryGirl.create(:contact)` within your test/spec.

To create a `user` and assign the id into the `dest_user_id` field on the `contact` you would use the following:

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
@contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact_with_user, :user => @user)
```

This approach maximises flexibility as you can create a `contact` with or without a user, and you can have the `user.id` passed into the contact model only if you need it for a particular test. If you call `FactoryGirl.create(:contact_with_user)` then both a `contact` and a `user` will automatically be created but you wouldn't have the control over the assignment of `dest_user_id` that you have when you use `FactoryGirl.create(:contact_with_user, :user => @user)`